# Umbraco 404 Issue

Tags: umbraco

I have setup 404 redirection successfully for an umbraco project. If the user navigates to a page that doesn't exist it shows the designated node id.
However consider this:

http://tsw/course-calendar/ - Correct Link

http://tsw/coursecalendar/ - Doesn't 404 (but should)

http://tsw/coursecalenda/ - 404 redirects

In the example above the correct link as per umbraco is the second however if I remove the dash but leave the words I get a Server error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.HomepageDTProxy', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TSW.Web.ViewModels.CourseCalendarVM'.
```

It's like the page is trying to resolve the URL.

How do I stop this behaviour in Umbraco so that only full and accurate links are opened and the remaining are 404 redirected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a doctype or template named coursecalendar? Then that might be it. If so, there are options to disable the URL resolving, see https://our.umbraco.com/forum/templates-partial-views-and-macros/ . The "switch" is disableAlternativeTemplates in umbracoSettings.config

Comment: I have a view called CourseCalendar yes but the no page titled that. Your explanation does make sense. I currently have disableAlternativeTemplates as false. Should I set this to true?

Comment: Shouldn't hurt to set it to true. If that doesn't work maybe try renaming your view to see if that's what causes it?